# Transparency not transparent in cycles. Darkness creeps!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

This has been driving me nuts. I need to add stickers to the round surface (basically a cylinder). Rendering in cycles.
Each time I try, I end up with a little dark bleed around the graphic.

Try 1: import image as plane with alpha. the Darkness is there.

Try 2: add contrast to the alpha. No joy. still darkness.

Try 3: go with the old image texture to diffuse, mix a transparency node with mix shader, use alpha in the factor of the mix shader.

Same darned darkness!

I can see it in the view port (screen shot) and in the final render, too.

What am I missing? This used to be easy.

Running blender 3.1.2

[image: cycles transparency not transparent!]

Comment: Make sure the stickers aren't exactly occupying the same space as the surface they're attached to (Face overlap causes transparency to go black in cycles). Make sure there's at least some very small offset (gap) between the sicker(s) and the cylinder.

Comment: Any reason, in this case, you can't round the sticker's  corners in geometry? that way, you'd get a little ping on the edges, too...

Comment: I had pulled them slightly forward on the x to bring them in front of the cylinder, so that “shouldn’t” be the problem. The artifact showed up when I tried the shrink wrap modifier with a bigger offset too.

Comment: Robin, I did think about tweaking the corners. I didn’t want to take the time to futz with beveling the corner verts. Lazy, I know. But the transparency node should show as clear, shouldn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

Christopher Bennett has it. I thought I had gaped it enough. Apparently, I was off by a smidge and they were overlapping.
Thank yoU!